# Parametrization of $V(x^2-y^2-1,x^2-z^2-1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, parametrization

For a field $K$ (we may assume it is infinite), I would like to give a parametric definition of the algebraic variety $V(x^2-y^2-1,x^2-z^2-1)\subset K^3$.

I was thinking that, if $K$ were for example $\mathbb{R}$, I could give this parametrization: $\{(\sqrt{t+1},\sqrt{t}),\sqrt{t}): t \in \mathbb{R}\}$. But I do not think I can take the square root in any field $K$, because I cannot assume it is algebraically closed. Also, even in $\mathbb{R}$, tha fact that I could have different signs for the square roots makes me think my parametrization is not correct.

Any help or hints would be really useful.

Comment: You get two hyperbolas, `ideal(y-z,x^2-z^2-1)` and `ideal(y+z,x^2-z^2-1)`. They can be rationally parameterized by $((1+t^2)/(2t), (1-t^2)/(2t),\pm (1-t^2)/(2t))$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland What strategy did you follow to find that parametrization? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: It's easily derived from the standard parameterization of $x^2+y^2-z^2=0, (s^2-t^2:2st:s^2+t^2)$ for $s=1$ and permuting the variables a bit.